# WiX: Change MsiExec.exe error message (not Windows Installer error messages)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a way to change error messages given by MsiExec in WiX?
My goal is to customize the message that appears when users try to install a patch without having the target product installed.

I have tried adding

```
<Error Id="1642">You must install my product before installing this patch.</Error>
```

to the UI section but it doesn't seem to work.

I suspect there is a big difference between [Windows Installer errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MsiExec errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot overwrite the texts of MsiExec. You can only overwrite some messages in the MSI tables "Error" and "ActionText", the latter is for messages during the installation process showing the progress bar.

The most important thing is, that the numbering in the "Error" table is an internal numbering and has nothing to do with the return error codes:

With WiX you can overwrite the content of the table "Error" but as you can see in your link or example msi files, especially the numbering is an own one and has nothing to do with the return codes (0, 1603, 3010, 1642,...) and their messages put out.
I think, most of these error messages are for the output in the logfile, but I think, their will be also some shown in a dialog, it has to be tried out.

For return error code 1642, the appropriate text is not in that table. There are patch related error messages like no. 1328 for examples, but their are for other scenarios.

But normally you don't let the user start by double click or typing in itself the msiexec command, do you?
Instead there is a **batch/script/setup.exe or installer service** doing this.

**And there you have to wrap the messages**. Many installations do this and start the install itself silent, e.g. with "`msiexec /quiet`" or "`msiexec /qn`"

Simplified batch example:

```
call msiexec /i "c:\mypath\mysetup.msi" /qn /L*v "c:\mylog.log"
SET SetupSuccess=%ERRORLEVEL%
if '%SetupSuccess%' EQU '0' echo Yes, setup successful.
if '%SetupSuccess%' EQU '1642' (
   echo.
   echo "You must install my product before installing this patch."
)
```

(Of course better with structured if/else, but it depends which return codes you want to give own messages.)

Comment: I do have an executable that launches msiexec but it runs with full UI so users will see the error message. I suppose I could check the target product exists before attempting to install the patch. It just seems redundant.

Comment: Windows Installer will discover that error before your patch does anything. If the target product isn't installed then Windows deals with that, not you. You can make your own message if you wrap your patch with an executable that first sees if your productcode is installed. Go even further and see if the installed version is lower than your patch version if you want to say it doesn't apply (or is already installed) in your own words. MsiGetProductInfo() and MsiApplyPatch()

Comment: Yes, I agree with PhilDW. It is not at all redundant but a good way to check it before. One specific function for testing, if the patch is applicable, is MsiDeterminePatchSequence(). I haven't used it myself, but after second reading the doc, it seems not so inconvenient, as after reading the first time. :-)